# Why thread can't be interrupted in ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I've done a simple test, and code as below :

```
    public class InterruptTest
    {
        public static class MyTask implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("before sleep " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                System.out.println("after sleep " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] str)
        {
            ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            // MyTask task1 = new MyTask();
            Future<?> future1 = service.submit(new InterruptTest.MyTask());
            Future<?> future2 = service.submit(new InterruptTest.MyTask());

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("interrupted;");
            }
        }
}
```

And the output is :

```
before sleep false
Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
after sleep true
**before sleep false** // line 4
Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
after sleep true
```

why line 4 still output false ? not true ? Cause there is only one thread in current pool, and it should have been interrupted in the first task, why it's still available (not interrupted) when the second task runs ?

Thanks in advance!

Another question is I modify the run function as below :

```
    public static class MyTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("before sleep " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("interrupted;");
            System.out.println("after sleep " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }
}
```

And the output of one task is :

```
before sleep false
Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
interrupted;
after sleep false
```

The task should be waked up from sleep by thread.interrupt. But when I use Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() to check it, it still return false.

Will sleep() eat the interrupt state ??

Comment: No, `sleep()` doesn't swallow the interrupted state. Throwing an `InterruptedException` (somewhat perversely) doesn't result in the interrupted flag being set on the interrupted thread: that is why you need to manually reinterrupt the current thread if you catch an `InterruptedException` and you are unwilling or unable to propagate that exception, but want to preserve the evidence that the thread was interrupted for callers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, there is a private method called [`clearInterruptsForTaskRun`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#ThreadPoolExecutor.clearInterruptsForTaskRun%28%29) documented as:

> Ensures that unless the pool is stopping, the current thread does not have its interrupt set

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found code related in runWorker: